# Cauchy Schwarz with integrals of integrable functions

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality

I was reading and doing problems from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. Q1-6 (a) stumped me a little.

Let $f$, $g$ be integrable on $[a,b]$.
Prove that $$\left| \int_a^b f\cdot g \; \right | \leq \left(\int_a^b f^2\right)^{1/2} \cdot \left (\int_a^b g^2\right )^{1/2}$$

*Hint*: Consider separately the cases 
$0=\int_a^b \left(f-\lambda g\right)^2$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, and $0<\int_a^b \left(f-\lambda g\right)^2$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.

The second case is fine. Square out the brackets, use linearity of the integral and you get a quadratic in $\lambda$ with no real roots so the discriminant is negative, that's that.

But for the first case the subtlety is that $f$ and $g$ are integrable not necessarily *continuous*. So we can have $f\neq \lambda g$.

What I tried to do was the same thing is use the discriminant again but that gives the inequality the other way around, which suggest that if it holds, the polynomial in $\lambda$ can only have repeated roots. But I can't prove the roots are not distinct.

My other approach would be to say that the integrand is positive and that we can split $[a,b]$ into intervals whereby $f-\lambda g=0$ but I'm not sure how to apply integrability to the points $x$ where $f(x)\neq\lambda g(x)$ which I would assume are isolated and possibly finite.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help you, but recall that $f,g$ being Riemann integrable means that they have at most countable discontinuities, the value of which does not effect the integral,  so you can probably "work around" any places they are not equal by an argument that its the same as an integral in which they are equal.  This is a comment and not an answer because I'm not 100% sure that will work :)

Comment: @Alan The book most certainly works with lebesgue integrability ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Alan. I couldn't remember myself the allowed number of discontinuities. I think I also need continuity almost everywhere with that, just from a quick Wikipedia :)

Comment: Ahh,  lebesgue integrable is even simpler, you just need continuous on all but a set of measure 0, and the value of the lebesgue integral on measure 0 sets is 0,  therefore you can safely excise them without any change to the value

Comment: @alan, he does introduce the use of a measure later on, like the idea of zero measure and content sets and  but this is fairly early on in the book. I didn't expect to take so long on the first set of exercises :)

Comment: @alexr I think he might do by the chapter on integration, but this is only the first chapter with no mention of measure. I'd like to see if I/it can be done without lebesgue measure?

Comment: @snulty Then if $f$ is Riemann integrable with $\int f = 0$ and $f\ge 0$ we have $f(x) = 0$ for all but countably many $x$

Comment: @AlexR: That is actually not correct. If $C$ denotes the Cantor set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), then the indicator function $\chi_C$ of the Cantor set is Riemann-integrable with integral $0$, but $\chi_C (x) \neq 0$ for each $x \in C$ and $C$ is uncountable.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see, I trusted Alan's first comment there - maybe you should ping him too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. We simply note that, since the integrand is nonnegative:
$$
0\leq \int (f-\lambda g)^2 dx = \int f^2 dx -2\lambda \int fg dx +\lambda ^2 \int g^2dx = \alpha \cdot \lambda^2 - 2\beta \lambda +\gamma
$$
with the obvious choices of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Observe that $\alpha \geq 0$, so that there are two cases:

1. $\alpha=0$. This implies $\beta=0$ (otherwise, let $\lambda \to \pm \infty$ depending on the sign of $\beta$ to get a contradiction. But for $\beta =0$, the claim is trivial.
2. $\alpha >0$. Here, we get
   $$
   0\leq (\sqrt{\alpha}\lambda - \beta/\sqrt{\alpha})^2 +\gamma - \beta^2/\alpha .
   $$
   A suitable choice of $\lambda$ makes the bracket vanish, which easily implies the claim.

EDIT: These considerations show that we do not need to distinguish the cases given in the hint, **as long as we are not interested in a criterion for equality**, but your are only asking for a proof of the inequality, not for a characterization of the case in which equality holds.

Comment: We'll see the problem was, as you said, to do it using the hint. Am I'm kind of curious to do that. But I do like your approach otherwise!

Comment: *Well (not we'll) , *and (not am) - autocorrect I hope :) I (+1)'d for the good answer though